# pod 'MaterialComponents' not adding all material components

Tags: ios, github, material-components

I followed the [**Github**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) link for installing **MaterialComponents** via pods. Though installation was successful, but could not find **MaterialTextFields**. Later noticed that for installing separate components, we have to use different pods. I also noticed that pod **MaterialComponents** itself installs many components.
My query is, on what basis, are there different pods for different components considering that many components are installed using single pod (**MaterialComponents**) as well. Why not have a same pod for all components OR why not have separate pod for each component.

Answer (score 1):

We only landed MaterialTextFields in the [24.0.0 release](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/releases/tag/v24.0.0) 8 days go. Perhaps you saw that it landed in develop earlier and expected it to be in our podspec?

All of our components should come if you add the root podspec target as instructed on the main readme. We setup subspecs so that clients can pick and choose which components they want to use if they are size averse.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the material buttons.

In my case I had to add `use_frameworks!` to the Podfile. It would be nice it this was added to the documentation.

Without the `use_frameworks!` the import was giving the error `No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons'`.